# It is possible increase the ###NEWS_AUTHOR### field in tt_news?

Tags: html, typo3, typoscript, tt-news

I need to increase the ###NEWS_AUTHOR### field for tt_news plugin for typo3. I need to add multiple authors to the news, but there isn't enough space in this field to add them all.

It is possible to change this?

Answer (score 2):

Add following lines to `typo3conf/extTables.php`

```php
$TCA['tt_news']['columns']['author']['config']['max'] = 255;
$TCA['tt_news']['columns']['author']['config']['size'] = 100;
```

But rememebr that the database field itself has a limitation of 255 chars (MySQL: `author varchar(255) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL`) defined in `/typo3conf/ext/tt_news/ext_tables.sql`

Comment: I have try this, but this is not working for me... If I add this lines to extTables.php, i can't edit and see the news.

Answer (score 1):

As Merec pointed - varchar() has limitations, if you need to add much more than that, maybe it will be better if you'll create an small extension which will extend `tt_news` table with new field (ie `mediumtext`) and then will add custom marker to the template?

You'll find info about this process in `tt_news` documentation.